# is it possible to filter on a vector in-place?

Tags: iterator, rust

I'd like to remove some elements from a `Vec`, but `vec.iter().filter().collect()` creates a new vector with borrowed items.

I'd like to mutate the original `Vec` without extra memory allocation (and keep memory of removed elements as an extra capacity of the vector).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to remove elements, you can use [`retain()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain), which removes elements from the vector if the closure returns `false`:

```
let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
vec.retain(|&x| x % 2 == 0);
assert_eq!(vec, [2, 4]);
```

If you want to modify the elements in place, you have to do that in a `for x in vec.iter_mut()`.

Comment: I am surprised that retain doesn't return the removed items. If you need those, you still need to come up with a verbose solution.

Answer (score 13):

If you truly want to mutate the vector's elements *while* filtering it, you can use the nightly-only method [`Vec::drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain_filter), an extremely flexible tool:

```
#![feature(drain_filter)]

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    vec.drain_filter(|x| {
        if *x % 2 == 0 {
            true
        } else {
            *x += 100;
            false
        }
    });
    assert_eq!(vec, [101, 103]);
}
```

It also allows you to get the removed elements as the return value of the entire method is an iterator!

Comment: Still nightly only. Can't wait to be able to use this during the day...

Comment: This has been renamed to `extract_if()`

Answer (score 2):

Till [`Vec::drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain_filter) gets stable, we can solve the problem with homebrewed rust:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < v.len() {
        if v[i] % 2 == 0 {
            v.remove(i);
        } else {
            v[i] += 100;
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);  // [101, 103]
}
```

BTW `remove()` is an `O(n)` operation but doesn't allocate memory.
[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=823eb8cd300963a40ce3e75eff578beb)

Answer (score 0):

I am providing my take for this problem as I was unaware of the retain method:

```
impl<T> RemoveFilter<T> for Vec<T> {}
pub trait RemoveFilter<T>: BorrowMut<Vec<T>> {
    fn remove_filter<F: for<'b> FnMut(&'b T) -> bool>(&mut self, mut cb: F) {
        let vec: &mut Vec<T> = self.borrow_mut();
        let mut write_to = 0;
        let mut read_from = 0;
        while read_from < vec.len() {
            let maintain = cb(&mut vec[read_from]);
            if maintain {
                vec.as_mut_slice().swap(read_from, write_to);
                write_to += 1;
            }
            read_from += 1;
        }
        vec.resize_with(write_to, || panic!("We are shrinking the vector"));
    }
}
```

It will shift the elements as it iterates and then remove anything that is left behind. I think this is code may easily modified to solve other problems.

Comment: Remarks: This solution will do a lot of bound checks due to the `swap` function. Since `read_from` is always smaller than `vec.len()` and write_to is alway smaller or equal than `read_from`, the swap function could be replaced with `swap_unchecked`. I prefer to use the safe version.