# Unable to collect a filtered a Vec into itself

Tags: filter, rust, prime-factoring

I've started working through the Project Euler problems in Rust and [came across #3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) where the easiest quick-approach would be to implement a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

In doing so, my algorithm creates an iterator to then filter non-primes out of and assign it back to the original vector, but I'm receiving an error that `Vec<u32>` can't be built from `Iterator<Item=&u32>`.

---

Code:

```
fn eratosthenes_sieve(limit: u32) -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut primes: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let mut range: Vec<u32> = (2..=limit).collect();
    let mut length = range.len();

    loop {
        let p = range[0];
        primes.push(p);

        range = range.iter().filter(|&n| *n % p != 0).collect();

        if length == range.len() {
            break;
        }
        length = range.len();
    }

    primes
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<u32>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&u32`
  --> src\main.rs:42:55
   |
42 |         range = range.iter().filter(|&n| *n % p != 0).collect();
   |                                                       ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<u32>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&u32>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&u32>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
```

---

Why is the closure wrapping the values in extra borrows?

Comment: This is not actually the Sieve of Eratosthenes; this is trial division. The difference is that in trial division, you test for divisibility by `p` all numbers not divisible by a prime less than `p`; in the sieve of Eratosthenes, you only deal with every `p`th number whether or not it has already been tested for divisibility by a smaller prime. I encourage you to read [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf), which analyzes the time complexity of both methods and describes a neat iterator-like way to implement the true sieve.

Comment: (Of course, if trial division is adequate for solving the problem, there is no shame to be had in using the slower method, especially if it is more readable.)

Comment: @trentcl I haven't had a math class in some 10 years so the direction is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe not *quite* a duplicate of [is it possible to filter on a vector in-place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913384/is-it-possible-to-filter-on-a-vector-in-place)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Explanation

According to the error message, the expression `range.iter().filter(|&n| *n % p != 0)` is an iterator over items of type `&u32`: a reference to an `u32`. You expected an iterator over `u32` by value. So let's walk backwards:

The `filter(...)` part of the iterator chain has actually nothing to do with your problem. When we take a look at [`Iterator::filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter), we see that it returns [`Filter<Self, P>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/iter/struct.Filter.html). This type implements `Iterator`:

```
impl<I: Iterator, P> Iterator for Filter<I, P>
where
    P: FnMut(&I::Item) -> bool,
{
    type Item = I::Item;
    // ...
}
```

The important part here is that `type Item = I::Item`, meaning that the item type of `I` (the original iterator) is passed through exactly. No reference is added.

This leaves `.iter()`: that's the cause of the problem. [`Vec::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html?search=#method.iter) returns [`slice::Iter<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) which implements `Iterator`:

```rust
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    // ...
}
```

And here we see that the item type is a reference to `T` (the element type of the vector).

#### Solutions

In general cases, you could call `.cloned()` on any iterator that iterates over references to get a new iterator that iterates over the items by value (by cloning each item). For types that implement `Copy` you can (and should) use `.copied()`. E.g. `range.iter().filter(|&n| *n % p != 0).copied().collect()`.

*However*, in this case there is a better solution: since you don't need the vector afterwards anymore, you can just call `into_iter()` instead of `iter()` in order to directly get an iterator over `u32` by value. This consumes the vector, making it inaccessible afterwards. But, as said, that's not a problem here.

```rust
range = range.into_iter().filter(|&n| n % p != 0).collect();
```

Also note that I removed the `*` in `*n`, as the dereference is not necessary anymore.

#### Other hints

Always reallocating a new vector is not very fast. The Sieve of Eratosthenes is classically implemented in a different way: instead of storing the numbers, one only stores Booleans to denote for each number if it's prime or not. The numbers are never stored explicitly, but implicitly by using the indices of the vector/array.

And to make it really fast, one should not use a `Vec<bool>` but instead a dedicated bitvec. `Vec<bool>` stores one byte per `bool`, although only one bit would be necessary. The de-facto crate that offers such a bit vector is `bit-vec`, which conveniently also shows an example implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes [in its documentation](https://docs.rs/bit-vec/0.6.1/bit_vec/).