# Remove elements of vector in a loop based on index

Tags: vector, rust, borrow-checker

Let's say I have a vector, the values are from 1 to 10. I want that if you find 5 and 5 next to each other, remove them together with the next elements.

input

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

expected output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This was my attempt. I'm finding index to remove, but borrowing rules are making me stuck.

```
let mut element = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (index, val) in element.iter().enumerate() {
    if *val == 5 {
        if let Some(next_val) = element.get(index + 1) {
            if *next_val == 5 {
                //element.drain(index..);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: windows from slice and position from iterator might also help ;), here is the solution [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a6e5d568916b0e26bc9cd0144c5a31f)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rust is saving you from *iterator invalidation* (a common source of bugs in other languages). This is an error that usually happens when you try to modify a data structure while concurrently iterating over it. You cannot move on to the (now-deleted) next element after calling `element.drain(index..)`. So you need to add a `break` after that point to avoid memory unsafety.

In this case just adding `break;` is sufficient to make the code compile. However, for a more concise, linear solution, take full advantage of the iterators and methods provided by the standard library:

```
if let Some(index) = element.windows(2).position(|pair| pair[0] == pair[1]) {
    element.truncate(index);
}
```

`windows(2)` on a slice gives an iterator over subslices of length 2, and the `position` call returns the index of the first element of that iterator for which the two elements of the slice are equal. (If no such pair exists, `position` returns `None`.)

I find that the `position` closure becomes more obvious with the (currently unstable) `array_windows` feature:

```
if let Some(index) = element.array_windows().position(|[x, y]| x == y) {
    element.truncate(index);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8224dca0e4c87a639e17187764aebcc2)

### Related

- [is it possible to filter on a vector in-place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913384/is-it-possible-to-filter-on-a-vector-in-place)

Comment: Alternative array windows for stable: `.windows(2).flat_map(TryInto::<[i32; 2]>::try_into).position(|[x, y]| x == y)` , [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ea41b4c2cafda575b98ff5f2638e9ff)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want to do because you want to remove some elements from a vector while you are iterating it. And this is a big mistake. Note that removing any elements from a vector invalidates the iterators, hence you will access unexpected locations so rust doesn't allow `UB`s
You can use something like the following

```rust
    let mut elements = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let mut first_repeated_five_index_op = None;
    for index in 0..elements.len()-1{
        if elements[index] == 5 && elements[index + 1] == 5{
            first_repeated_five_index_op = Some(index);
            break;
        }
    }
    if let Some(first_repeated_five_index) = first_repeated_five_index_op{ 
          elements.truncate(first_repeated_five_index);
    }
    println!("{:?}", elements);
```

See a [Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e74e04161c92a5403f4b32ef103dccfc)

Comment: Nitpick: *removing* elements from a vector does not cause reallocation. However you are right to point out that it still invalidates extant references to the vector (including the iterator).

Comment: [Shift everything down to fill in that spot.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.54.0/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs#L1403), removing doesn't change the actual capacity of vector, which causes the reallocation, there will be no change unless you call the `Vec::shrink_to_fit`

Comment: @ÖmerErden Thank u. I thought it looks like C++