# Can't borrow mutable values inside loop

Tags: rust, mutability

I'm trying to remove an element from an array:

```
pub fn update(arr: &mut Vec<Pipe>) {
        // move pipes
        for pipe in arr.iter_mut() { //first mutable borrow occurs here
            pipe.pos.x -= 2.;

            if pipe.pos.x < 20. {
                arr.remove(0); //seconds mutable borrow
            }
        }
    }
```

Error :

```
cannot borrow `*arr` as mutable more than once at a time
second mutable borrow occurs here
```

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: You can't mutate an array whilst iterating it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to filter on a vector in-place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913384/is-it-possible-to-filter-on-a-vector-in-place)

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the first element and not the current element? @user1937198, this also affects whether this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Work on a newly created copy of the array.
For that the `Pipe` type must be cloneable:

```
pub fn update(arr: &mut Vec<Pipe>) {
    *arr = arr.into_iter()
    .map(|mut p| {p.pos.x -= 2.0; (*p).clone()})
    .filter(|p| p.pos.x >= 20.0)
    .collect();
}
```

With the [user1937198 hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913384/is-it-possible-to-filter-on-a-vector-in-place) you can do this two-step-solution ─
throw the less-20-pipes out first and iterate afterwards:

```
pub fn update(arr: &mut Vec<Pipe>) {
    arr.retain(|p| p.pos.x >= 22.0);
    for pipe in arr.iter_mut() {
        pipe.pos.x -= 2.0;
    }
}
```

Both solutions assume, that the currently tested `Pipe` must be removed and not the first one.